# Install Deepin DE in Ubuntu 20.04: qtbase-abi-5-9-5 package

Tags: apt, 20.04, deepin-desktop-environment

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and wanted to try the Deepin Desktop Environment which looks great.
I added the PPA (`ppa:leaeasy/dde`) to the known repositories as recommended. But there are some dependencies that cannot be resolved when trying `apt install dde`.

The package `qtbase-abi-5-9-5` cannot be installed: 
It looks like to be a virtual package that points to `libqt5core5a` which is already installed.
The real package is installed but the virtual package is not referenced as installed.

This library is used by Plasma and many others so I don't really want to uninstall/reinstall it with the virtual package.

Is there an easy workaround to get the `qtbase-abi-5-9-5` package "installed" or bypass this dependency when installing DDE?

EDIT:
`apt-cache policy dde`

```
  dde:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 15.4+16
  Version table:
     15.4+16 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: It is unclear which PPA provides package for *focal*. Please add output of `apt-cache policy dde` to the question body.

Comment: This PPA is exclusively for *bionic*, but I enabled the Ubuntu repositories for this release too. Actually, I don't know if that should work correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 20200515:**

UbuntuDDE team has provided [stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntudde-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable). You can install packages from it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
sudo apt-get install ubuntudde-dde
```

---

Tried to fix this in a fast way on VM, downloaded a dozen of deb-packages including [`libqt5core5a`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/libqt5core5a) which provides *qtbase-abi-5-9-5* and got serious dependency issue. Manual installation of packages from different releases may harm your system, so it is safer to revert these changes and to wait for packages with DDE specially prepared for 20.04 LTS.

Also I have [searched the LaunchPad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) and found other PPA from Ubuntu DDE team - [`ppa:openarun/dde-dev`](https://launchpad.net/~openarun/+archive/ubuntu/dde-dev). It allows to install DDE on Focal.

So you have to remove other PPA(s) by commands like:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:leaeasy/dde
```

and add this PPA to the system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openarun/dde-dev
sudo apt-get install ubuntudde-*
```

and then it should work:

[image: Ubuntu DDE login]

[image: Ubuntu DDE desktop]

Comment: This PPA is what is needed! Thanks! I used to search for PPA with Google which doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: How did you pick that ppa over all the others which provide deepin packages? Official team?

Comment: By visiting https://launchpad.net/ubuntudde , https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas , using deduction and logic :)

Comment: use sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable . This is the updated and most secure way .

Comment: Every time I try this it doesn't work.

Comment: Job for deepin-anything-tool.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status deepin-anything-tool.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Answer (score 4):

There is a stable UbuntuDDE release for focal fossa here: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntudde-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

I have tried it out on my focal installation successfully.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntudde-dde
```