# how to install the DDE to the ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: repository, 20.04, deepin-desktop-environment

I have installed the Ubuntu 20.04, and want now I want to install Deepin Desktop Environment (dde)

My steps are:

- add the ppa and install using apt

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt install dde
  ```

But during the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde` I get the following error:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
 You can install deepin desktop environment by run

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install dde
------
Ubuntu Bionic: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xkQPb4tWocknuYeY-t41W--kz-9SSL0V/view?usp=sharing
------
Important Issue:
Q: Can dde on Ubuntu 16.04?
A: Sorry, the dde depends on qt version above than 5.6.
     If you want to install dde, please upgrade to 17.04 or above.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~leaeasy/+archive/ubuntu/dde
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                     
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                   
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu focal InRelease                                     
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease           
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu focal Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I get the similar error with `sudo apt-get update` :

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                      
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                    
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I install dde ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/866901/590937

Comment: it's not helping, can we add the ppa without trust somehow?

Comment: No, you have to remove this ppa since it only has packages for Artful and Zesty, but not for Focal. You may contact the maintainer of the ppa as described in the linked answers.

Comment: ok, so can we manually download and install, if yes, then how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Deepin DE in Ubuntu 20.04: qtbase-abi-5-9-5 package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230282/install-deepin-de-in-ubuntu-20-04-qtbase-abi-5-9-5-package)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per answer here you can fix the error you are getting.

[Install Deepin DE in Ubuntu 20.04: qtbase-abi-5-9-5 package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230282/install-deepin-de-in-ubuntu-20-04-qtbase-abi-5-9-5-package)

In short, you need to use `ppa:openarun/dde-dev`

Looks like `ppa:openarun/dde` doesn't support **focal** release yet.